# If the title is called Scorch Trials, what are the trials in the movie itself?

Tags: title, maze-runner-the-scorch-trials

In the **Maze Runner** series, after the *Maze Runner* itself, comes the *Maze Runner **Scorch Trials***.

Now, I have seen both movies more than once, and in the Scorch Trials, there is no actual *trials* in itself.

In the *Scorch Trials* what are the actual tests given to the gladers for them to complete other than **draining them**?

**Thomas** and the rest of his friends escape from there, run away and found the **Right Arm**.

Why is the movie title called **Scorch Trials** when there are no actual tests given to complete? That is what trials means: Tests. So why is it called that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct...there are no **specific** tests but "trials" also has a different meaning..

> a person, experience, or situation that tests a person's endurance.
>
> <sup>[Source](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/trial)</sup>

So a "trial" doesn't have to be a **defined** test but rather an experience which, **as a byproduct**, *happens* to test a person's abilities or fortitude.

---

**Out of Universe**.

The movie is an loose adaptation of the book with that [title](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Scorch_Trials) so it would make sense to make use of the name.